# How rewrite my for loop to use shorter code

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code that I hope could be rewritten to use shorter code.
The code work fine but I just feel like the code is circum.
Here some basic about the code
Dictionary dict = settings.files;
occurences is an object with some property but one is named FileName

```
string fileNameShort;
List<Common.Occurences> filteredList = new List<Occurences>();


//Lookup the right dictionary item for given filename in occurences
for (int j = 0; j < settings.files.Count; j++)
{
    if (occurences.FileName.StartsWith(dict.Keys.ElementAt(j)))
    {
        fileNameShort = dict.Keys.ElementAt(j);

        if (dict[fileNameShort])
        {
            filteredList.Add(occurences);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `dict`?

Comment: It's a dictionary

Comment: Of type.......?

Comment: Dictionary<string, bool> dict = settings.files;

Comment: Why use a dictionary if you don't intend to use it as such? It seems really odd to get the keys every time and walk over the entire dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredList = (from entry in dict where entry.Value && occurence.FileName.StartsWith(entry.Key) select occurence).ToList();
```

Maybe it would be helpful to insert line breaks somewhere.

**Edit:** What strikes me though is that the list will contain only repetitions of the same object `occurences`, since this does not depend on the index `j` in your code.

Comment: For example occurences.FileName = "babspaylink_cashit-bpti.1.log" but settings.files contain in one place  {babspaylink,true} where key is bapspaylink and the value is true.

Comment: So the key in dictionary is sometimes different then the filename in occurences

Comment: @tony Yes, but if you have e.g. {babspaylink, true} and {babspay, true} in the dictionary, you will get a list with two times the same item. The list can never contain two different items, which is why it is a bad idea to use List.

Comment: In this project we never have key name like babspaylink and bapspay.the key we use are always unique.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start

```
foreach(var j in settings.files.Where(x => occurences.Filename.StartsWith(x.Key))
{
    filteredList.Add(j);
}
```

but it nowhere near what you need because your code makes no sense - to me atleast.

Comment: public class Occurences<br/>
    {
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Occurance { get; set; }
        public string ForeColor { get; set; }
        public string BackColor { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }

Comment: if the dictionary holds to entire filename, then why use StartsWith() ?

Comment: Also; no need for a dictionary. You can use use a List<occurence> and access the FileName property

Comment: The point is that I use settings.files which is a dictionaty<string,bool> in the winform as checkbox to be checked if true else unchecked. As I mentioned before the occurences.FileName is sometimes different then the key in settings.files. So I want to add the object occurences to filteredList if the occurences.FileName startwith a name that also exist as a key in dictionary.

Comment: One more comment I only add to filteredList if the value is true for the found key